# How to update a tab view from child page in Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

So I'm trying to update a list view in a parent tab window using Angular.js with the Ionic Framework, but I can't quite seem to figure out how to do it.

Here is the code for the child window:

```
    $scope.currentUsername = Parse.User.current().get("username");

$scope.saveChanges = function saveChanges(user){
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    var newUserName = user.newUsername;

    currentUser.set("username", newUserName);
    currentUser.save(null, {
        success: function(currentUser){
        alert("Changes successfully made!");
        }
    });
    $state.go('tab.more');
}

$scope.cancelChanges = function cancelChanges(){
$state.go('tab.more');
}
```

And I am trying to take the data once it's sent to Parse back to the parent view but I don't know how to refresh the page after the script is run. In my function cancelChanges() I simply used $state.go to go back to the parent view because why update the view when there is not data to be updated.

Here is the code for my parent window:

```
    $scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current().get("username");

$scope.editProfile = function editProfile(){
$state.go('tab.more-editusername');
}

$scope.logOut = function logOut(){
Parse.User.logOut();
alert("Logout successful!");
$state.go('login');
}
```

Comment: use `$emit` event or call `$scope.$parent.parentMethodName()` if you mentained proper hierarchy of controller

Answer (score 0):

ionic views are cached by default... so I do not believe the update is happening unless you force it to

**From Documentation**

> *View LifeCycle and Events Views can be cached, which means controllers normally only load once, which may affect your controller
>   logic. To know when a view has entered or left, events have been added
>   that are emitted from the view's scope. These events also contain data
>   about the view, such as the title and whether the back button should
>   show. Also contained is transition data, such as the transition type
>   and direction that will be or was used.*

you can try and listen for the `$ionicView.enter` event and then update the view with the new data